# position-independent comparison of Hangul characters

Tags: python, unicode, comparison

I am writing a python3 program that has to handle text in various writing systems, including Hangul (Korean) and I have problems with the comparison of the same character in different positions.
For those unfamiliar with Hangul  (not that I know much about it, either), this script has the almost unique feature of combining the letters of a syllable into square blocks. For example 'ㅎ' is pronounced [h] and 'ㅏ' is pronounced [a], the syllable 'hah' is written '핳' (in case your system can't render Hangul: the first h is displayed in the top-left corner, the a is in the top-right corner and the second h is under them in the middle). Unicode handles this by having two different entries for each consonant, depending on whether it appears in the onset or the coda of a syllable. For example, the previous syllable is encoded as '\u1112\u1161\u11c2'.
My code needs to compare two chars, considering them as equal if they only differ for their positions. This is not the case with simple comparison, even applying Unicode normalizations. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a tailored version of the Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA) that assigns equal weights to identical syllables. The [UCA technical report](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Hangul_Collation) describes the general problem for sorting Hangul.

Luckily, the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) has a set of collation rules that does exactly this: `ko-u-co-search` – Korean (General-Purpose Search); which you can try out on their [demo page](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/collation.html). To use this in Python, you will either need use a library like [PyICU](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU/), or one that implements the UCA and supports the ICU rule file format (or lets you write your own rules).

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer for Python [jamo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jamo) (the Hangul letters are called jamo). An easy way to do this would be to cast all jamo code points to their respective Hangul compatibility jamo (HCJ) code points. HCJ is the display form of jamo characters, so initial and final forms of consonants are the same code point.

For example:

```
>>> import jamo
>>> initial, vowel, final = jamo.j2hcj('\u1112\u1161\u11c2')
>>> initial == final
True
```

The way this is done internally is with a lookup table copied from the Unicode specifications.